# ClassNotFoundException error is displayed in the console when i tried to launch chrome browser using selenium with java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

just getting started with Eclipse + Java + Selenium.

Not doing anything fancy -

My code looks like this:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

When I run, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

I have selenium-java-2.48.2.jar in my Java Build Path.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add your stacktrace, so I could see the full exception messge.

Comment: Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available
TestApp.main(String[]) line: 9

Comment: the class it cannot find is "ChromeDriver"

Answer (score 0):

You need download [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) first, once you download it, place executable inside your project and set chromedriver property, it should be something like:

**project_folder**
- src 
- chromedriver.exe

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Tried all that, didn't help:

public class TestApp {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 }
}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
 at com.test.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 1 more

Comment: Is there test runner in place, JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: I see now, you missing test runner (just use JUnit or TestNG) and annotate your test methods with @Test tag, also keep  your tests in src/test not in src/main.

Comment: okay, so I am going to install JUNIT based on http://junit.sourceforge.net/, unzip junit*.jar to some directory, setup environment variable CLASSPATH to include that.

Comment: I install junit-4.10.jar into some directory.  Then I pointed my project Java Build Path -> Libraries -> include junit-4.10.jar.  Tried running, still didn't work.

Comment: Have you moved your tests to src/test folder? And don't forget tag your methods with @Test annotation

Answer (score 0):

```
        String WEB_DRIVER_PATH="";
        String url=URL_TO_HIT_ON_BROWSER;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", WEB_DRIVER_PATH);
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url +"/");
```

use updated jars.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

@Test
public void goToWebsite() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

and then run goToWebsite

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using 2.XX version of selenium because the problem you are facing is the same i faced when i moved my existing scripts from selenium 2 to Selenium 3.
You need to set the path of the chromedriver first.
Steps-
 1. Download chromedriver.exe compatible for your environment.
 2. Set the path of chromedriver.Add the following line of code before making ChromeDriver object.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your class file is in a source folder. If it is not, right click on the folder, choose Build Path > Use as source folder

Make sure all your jars are in the build path. I also suggest that you use Maven to help you organize jars as dependencies

After these, you must download the chromedriver.exe file from here:
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Place the chromedriver.exe file in any accessible directory and set the web driver environment property by inserting this line on your code before instantiating your driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<pathToYourDriver>/chromedriver.exe");
```